# Absolute error computation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Given is a function $f(x)=4x^{2}$, which we want to evaluate for $x\in \left [ 1,2 \right ]$, $\widetilde{x}\in \left [ 1,2 \right ]$ is the approximation of $x$.

1. What can be the value of the absolute error of $\widetilde{x}$, so the absolute error of $f(\widetilde{x})$ is at most 2?
2. What can be the value of the absolute error of $\widetilde{x}$, so the absolute error of $f(\widetilde{x})$ is at most 11%?

Ok, here is my try. I use the following notation: $\bigtriangleup x=x-\widetilde{x} $, $\bigtriangleup f=f(x)-f(\widetilde{x})$. 
I can use the statement $\bigtriangleup f=\left | f'(x) \right |\bigtriangleup x$. Now i have to look for such $\bigtriangleup x$ that $\bigtriangleup f\leq 2$. Here comes my problem. I relalize that the minimum and the maximum of the function don't lay in the interval $[1,2]$. I see that from $f''(x)=0$ i get $x=0$, which makes me think that this approach can be wrong, because then i can't find $\bigtriangleup x$...

Can anybody help me with this problem, please? I appreciate any ideas and comments. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are approximating over $[1,2]$, you just need to find the maximum of the first derivatve of $f(x)$ over that interval.  Let $d=\max_{x \in [1,2]} |f'(x)|$.  Can you find that?  Then $\Delta f(x) \lt d \Delta x,\quad \Delta x = \frac {\Delta f(x)}d$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Obviously, $d=16$, so i got $\bigtriangleup x\leq \frac{1}{8}=0.125$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For the second part, it is a bit strange to quote absolute error as a percentage.  Reading it literally, you want the absolute error to be less than $0.11$, giving $\Delta x=\frac {0.11}{16}$  Because of the percentage, I suspect they really want relative error.  In that case, you need to find the maximum of $\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac d{dx}(\log f(x))$ over the region of interest.